# Keeping a rich:popupPanel open after page change

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Is it possible to keep a rich:popupPanel open after a form has been submitted and another page loaded?
As an example, go to [richfaces showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=simplePopup&skin=blueSky) and click "Call the popup" then browse somewhere else (using a tab like "Modal panel example" or the menu). The popup will disappear as soon as  the form gets submitted. I would like to let it "survive" the page change (and possibly remain in the same position).

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. You just need to set the attribute `show` to something that evaluates to true in the next request:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="popup" show="#{someBean.showPopup}" ...>
```

Then you just need to make sure the property the method getShowPopup returns `true` when the popup needs to be shown.

From [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/popupPanel.html):

> show | boolean | If "true" value for this attribute makes a modal
>   panel opened as default. Default value is "false"

See also [this section on rich:popupPanel](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Panels.html#sect-Component_Reference-richpopupPanel-Showing_and_hiding_the_pop-up).

Comment: show="true" works, thanks a lot! Do you know how can I let the popup remain on the same position when the user changes page?

Comment: @Federico Have you tried setting the `top` and `left` attributes? Take a look at the vdldocs: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/popupPanel.html If that doesn't work, you may need to apply some CSS.